# Unable to push records to store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

For some reason, I am unable to push records to the store. I have tried the most basic examples given from the [2.1 docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push) for the store.push and store.pushPayload examples.

I first tried using:

```
store.push(store.normalize('myModel', item));
```

then I tried

```
store.push({ 
  data: { 
    id: '666',
    type: 'myModel', 
    attributes: { name: "Bar" },
    relationships: { }
  }
});
```

The store.push when used (how I think is correct), returned nothing. I was able to run `store.peekAll('myModel').mapBy('name')`, and I saw the results of the data I pushed to the store. The data never appeared in the chrome ember inspector. When I used `this.store.peekAll('myModel')` in my route’s model, no results appeared whereas `this.store.findAll('myModel')` resulting data would render to my templates and appear in the chrome ember inpsector.

I’m trying to avoid a trip to the server and that is why I want to hydrate the store from data cached in localStorage, and so I’m using `peekAll`. Any ideas why I’m not seeing data I’m pushing to the store rendering in my templates or why the chrome ember inspector is not showing?

Edit:
I forgot to mention that I am not using the default JSONApi adapter. I am using the most recent version of active-model-adapter with the most recent version of ember-data (2.1 and I tried 2.2-beta3), and ember 2.1. I also have one model that uses LocalForage adapter/serializer and that one also does not work with being pushed to directly. However everything works so long as I use findAll instead of manually push records + peekAll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ricardo Mendes helped me figure out what I was doing wrong. I was using the **"store:main"** container.

```
App.__container__.lookup('store:main'); // ember 1.x
```

This does not fly with ember 2.0. The container needs to be **"service:store"** as in:

```
App.__container__.lookup('service:store'); // ember 2.x
```

I was using the API correctly, just pushing to the wrong store.